# Win Key + D should close menus

Tags: 20.04

When opening the windows / super menu, once open, the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> hotkey does not work.
Same behaviour is shown when any gnome menu is open

Where as in windows, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>> always works.

What would be the best way to make <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>> always work in the menus?

It's a hotkey that I use a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By default, <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> hides all windows on the current desktop (Note that <kbd>Super</kbd> is the win key). This is not relevant in the Overview (after you press <kbd>Super</kbd> on its own), so it should and will not work there.

In Ubuntu, system wide shortcut keys (<kbd>Super</kbd> to go to the overview, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the window, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to close applications) are not available while an application menu is open. You can only get away from the menu by closing it out (hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> will do). It is currently designed to work this way, and unfortunately cannot readily be changed without editing source code, or alternatively, filling an issue to the developers.